# Java script not starting when navigating to a page containing an applet

Tags: browser, java, opera

I am trying to run [this website](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/), which is supposed to run an applet (?) with Java script. It should look [like this](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/vfa2sample.html); however, the page is blank, except for the heading:

[image: Screen capture of what I see]

I have downloaded and unzipped the files in the upper right hand corner of the last linked page, although I don't know if I'm supposed to do anything with the downloaded files.

I have also included the website URL on the Exception Site List in the Java Control Panel.

I use Windows 10 and Opera as my browser. JavaScript is enabled in my browser.

Trying with Safari, IE or Chrome has been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much chasing around I was able to get the web-site to display correctly:-

- I used PaleMoon browser, which supports the Java plug-in, while Opera appears not to recognise it.
- I installed the latest Java version 8 update 161.
- I added `https://math.la.asu.edu` to the Java Control Panel exception list, without the rest of the address.

Java ran after the unsigned code was accepted, but it was quite slow - around 15 seconds before the content appeared.

Waterfox also supports the Java plug-in, but for some reason the Java content didn't load.

I was testing on Ubuntu, but browsers are generally compatible with Windows versions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish I could also up-vote your answer. Incidentally, do you have any words of wisdom as to why it is so darn complicated to get this thing running? Actually, in judging from the complexity of the answer, and the non-specific nature of the other suggestions, one may argue that there is more to my question to deserve the -1 that it got...

Comment: The reason is that the traditional method of importing plus-ins is thought to be not very secure, so modern browsers are requiring different standards, but Java/Oracle are not implementing these. Currently, web-sites are moving away from the use of Java for this reason. I use PaleMoon and Waterfox because I have web cameras that use Java, but whose firmware is no longer maintained. It is also useful for legacy web-sites (like yours!). Note that JavaScript is still available, but it is generally used to build web pages and is unsuitable for your sort of application.

Comment: I got it running, and after re-starting the browser, it won't start - there is a message reading, "A plugin is needed to display this content." I tried adding it as an extension, but the file extensions are different from the ones provided by the site repository. Do you know how to go around this?

Comment: Plug-ins are different from extensions: plug-ins are native code in the host OS and are stored in a particular directory for each browser; Mozilla extensions are written in JavaScript with various resource files, and they are transportable across operating systems. If you followed the instructions in [this link](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), then you may have to look for specific instructions for your browser: you need to copy or set a link to the Java library file into the plug-ins directory. Finding the correct plug-ins directory is what I found the most difficult part.

Answer (score 0):

It's not JavaScript, it is Java. JavaScript is the scripting engine used by browsers to allow dynamic webpages while Java is an object orientated programming language. They share some similarity in code style, but little more than that.

> Java is an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) language created by James Gosling of Sun Microsystems. JavaScript is a scripting language that was created by the fine people at Netscape and was originally known as LiveScript. JavaScript is a (very) distant cousin of Java in that it is also an OOP language. Many of their programming structures are similar. However, JavaScript contains a much smaller and simpler set of commands than does Java. It is easier for the average weekend warrior to understand.

Java has been discontinued for almost all current browsers due to security concerns. Almost no browser supports Java and so you will need to download the "jar" version and run it manually if you want to run it at all.

Comment: Very interesting, but can you help me with my question?

Comment: @justquestions  If there is a `.jar` file and you have Java installed then you can open a command prompt and run `java C:\path\to\jar.jar` but I have no idea if the applet is even compatible with current java versions.